# Get var from other function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Trying to use the value variable in the sendatta function, but i get "Undefined" in the emails that the account receives.

```
function GetDataFromSpreadsheet()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var value = range.getValues();

  return value;
}

function sendatta(value)
{
  MailApp.sendEmail("user.tryaccount@outlook.com", "subjects", value);
}
```

What do i need to do =) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable "value" exists only in the function `GetDataFromSpreadsheet()`, so your other function ignores it completely.

you have to define it using for example

```
var value = GetDataFromSpreadsheet();
```

That said, the value you return is a 2 dimensions array and you are using it as a string, is that intentional ?

Answer (score -1):

```
unction GetDataFromSpreadsheet()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var value = range.getValues();

  return value;
}

var value = GetDataFromSpreadsheet();

function sendatta(value)
{
  MailApp.sendEmail("user.tryaccount@outlook.com", "subjects", value);
}
```

OR

```
function sendatta()
{
  MailApp.sendEmail("user.tryaccount@outlook.com", "subjects", GetDataFromSpreadsheet());
}
```